# Using CASE for a specific situation - How TO

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to find the proper SQL for the following situation:

Supposed we have two tables:

```
TABLE A
ID int,
TEXT varchar(200)

TABLE B
ID int,
A_NO int,
B_NO int
```

Fields named "ID" on both tables can be join to link tables.

The following SQL:

```
SELECT
 A.ID,
 B.A_NO,
 B.B_NO
FROM
 A
LEFT JOIN
 B
ON A.ID = B.ID
ORDER BY A.ID, B.A_NO, B.B_NO
```

gives the following results:

[image]

Now, the problem.
What is asked for is to have in the column B_NO a value = 1 for the MIN value of column A_NO and a value = 0 for all the others row with the same A_NO value.
The results below are expected:

[image]

Please note that, in this example, we can find two rows for each B_NO value but it is possible to have more than 2 rows.

I have tried to reproduce these results by using a CASE but with no success.
Thanks for you help in advance,
Bouzouki.

Comment: This sounds like a homework or learning assignment.  What have you tried?  And, what database are you using?

Comment: No, not an homework (but I wish !!!). I successfully obtain the results but I use a CASE with a very long sub-query directly in the CASE. Even then, it was only for a specific ID. As I'm really not an expert in SQL, I have some problems to see how I can use a conditional statement to populate the field B_NO.

Comment: And, I'm using SQ Server 2008 R2.

Comment: you want to have in the column B_NO a value = B_NO if A_NO is the MIN value of column A_NO grouped by ID,B_NO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
    select ID, a_no, b_no, 
           case when a_no = min_a_no then b_no else 0 end as new_b_no
    from 
           a left join b on a.id = b.id left join
           (Select ID, B_no, min(a_no) as min_a_no
            from  a left join b on a.id = b.id
            group by id, b_no) m on a.id = m.id and b.b_no = m.b_no
    ORDER BY A.ID, B.A_NO
```

Comment: Many thanks for your clear SQL. It works perfectly. Kaf also put a good answer but your answer is most readable for inexperienced programmer. I hope that this will help people with similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()`; ([DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/deac3/1))

**Please note:** I have considered `myT` as your *joined query* of `A` *and* `B` tables for demo purpose. So replace *`myT`* with as yours *`A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID`*.

```
;with cte as (
  select id, a_no, b_no, 
         row_number() over(partition by id,b_no order by a_no) rn
  from myT
)
select id,a_no, case when rn=1 then b_no else 0 end b_no
from cte
order by a_no

--RESULTS FROM DEMO TABLE
|      ID | A_NO | B_NO |
-------------------------
| 1031014 |    1 |    1 |
| 1031014 |    2 |    0 |
| 1031014 |    3 |    2 |
| 1031014 |    4 |    0 |
| 1031014 |    5 |    3 |
| 1031014 |    6 |    0 |
| 1031014 |    7 |    4 |
| 1031014 |    8 |    0 |
| 1031014 |    9 |    5 |
| 1031014 |   10 |    0 |
```

Comment: Thanks Kaf. It works perfectly too. Beth's answer is probably easiest to manage for us. But I learn from your answer. Thanks again.